LNK2001 (and other linker errors) for no Apparent Reason
My problem is that I am getting linker errors with no apparent reason, so I will just share my source code immediately.
PZ_Buffer.h:
#pragma once

#include <glad/gl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>

class VertexBuffer
{
    uint32_t m_BufferID = 0;
public:
    VertexBuffer(std::vector<float> data, size_t size);
    ~VertexBuffer();

    void Bind() const;
    void Unbind() const;
};

class IndexBuffer
{
    uint32_t m_BufferID = 0;
    size_t m_Count = 0;
public:
    IndexBuffer(std::vector<uint32_t> data, size_t size, size_t count);
    ~IndexBuffer();

    inline size_t GetCount() { return m_Count; }

    void Bind() const;
    void Unbind() const;
};

PZ_Buffer.cpp:
#include "PZ_Buffer.h"

VertexBuffer::VertexBuffer(std::vector<float> data, size_t size)
    : m_BufferID(0)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_BufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_BufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size * sizeof(float), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

VertexBuffer::~VertexBuffer()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_BufferID);
}

void VertexBuffer::Bind() const
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_BufferID);
}

void VertexBuffer::Unbind() const
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

IndexBuffer::IndexBuffer(std::vector<uint32_t> data, size_t size, size_t count)
    : m_BufferID(0), m_Count(count)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_BufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_BufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, size * sizeof(uint32_t), data.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

IndexBuffer::~IndexBuffer()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_BufferID);
}

void IndexBuffer::Bind() const
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_BufferID);
}

void IndexBuffer::Unbind() const
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

I don't understand the why the problem is occurring, so it's nearly impossible for me to do anything. If it's any use, here is the errors from the console:
1>PZ_Level.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall VertexBuffer::~VertexBuffer(void)" (??1VertexBuffer@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall VertexBuffer::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GVertexBuffer@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>PZ_Level.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall VertexBuffer::Bind(void)const " (?Bind@VertexBuffer@@UBEXXZ)
1>PZ_Level.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall VertexBuffer::Unbind(void)const " (?Unbind@VertexBuffer@@UBEXXZ)
1>PZ_Level.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall IndexBuffer::~IndexBuffer(void)" (??1IndexBuffer@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall IndexBuffer::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GIndexBuffer@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>PZ_Level.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall IndexBuffer::Bind(void)const " (?Bind@IndexBuffer@@UBEXXZ)
1>PZ_Level.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall IndexBuffer::Unbind(void)const " (?Unbind@IndexBuffer@@UBEXXZ)

And my compiler is MSVC 2022 and please do not close without giving a notice, thank you.
Edit: I have read the Microsoft documentation on this error and the top answers on the question that I allegedly duplicated and they do not solve my problem; if the problem is with my compiler, explain thoroughly.

Add the files PZ_Buffer.* the the project.

The linker error has nothing to do with the libraries that I linked, however here is the source code: https://github.com/pmanpnd/pz.

Well, from the looks of it, you're either missing the VertexBuffer and IndexBuffer classes, or a library that's meant to provide them.

No library was meant to provide them, and I've checked .vcxproject file which definitely had the PZ_Buffer .h and .cpp files in them.

You need to link all of the relevant object code/files together -- whether they be libraries or your own code.

I checked .vcxproject file and  I've linked everything that needs to, I'm running the project from Visual Studio - not from the console.

Try a totally clean build.

As usual for other OPs on SO, you ignored the top messages in the build output. pz\bin\obj\Debug\x64\PZ_Buffer.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored - you have two files that are compiled into a single PZ_Buffer.obj, one of them does not have the required function definitions.

@273K So, can you tell me how to fix it if you think there's a solution.

The issue is here, the Item Type for PZ_Buffer.h is set to C/C++ compiler and generates yet another conflicting PZ_Buffer.obj w/o function definitions.

It must be set to C/C++ header.


The issue still persists :(.

No, it does not. Now you should rebuild the project to update PZ_Buffer.obj.

It does, https://imgur.com/a/dcKmD0t.

It does not. I've just checked your repo. The picture does not show that you have rebuilt the solution. Don't argue. You perhaps get other errors now. Also remove bin from the project. Why do you add .obj to there?

Ok thank you, I removed bin and now it worked.
